# Can I get a table script with its data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ado.net

I am using a SQL Server 2008 database.

I have two databases namely `db1` and `db2`. In both there is a table `tblcountry`. I create this on 1st database. Then how can I script with its data for create on 2nd database?

I use the code below

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblCountry]
(
    [record_Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [country] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
    [nationality] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
    [lsdMdfdOn] [datetime] NULL,
    [lstMdfdBy] [nvarchar](350) NULL,
    [isDeleted] [bit] NULL,
    [isEnabled] [bit] NULL,
)
```

Then what code will I use for the getting include the data?

Answer (score 1):

**No**, you cannot view the data if you are using the create query.

If you want to see the data of the table on second database then you can use this query on your second database db2

```
select * from [db1].[dbo].[tblCountry]
```

But you can not view the data and create query at the same time.

Although it may seem very wierd solution but I guess what you can do is you can copy the create query on the query analyzer window and beneath that write the select query and execute it. (*But I guess this is how most of the programmers do that*)

Comment: what you think about the import and export option in the sql server for this solution.I am not well known with sql server

Comment: @Safeena:- I would not recommend using Import/Export option for such a simple task. It is used for a very specific purpose mostly for integration services, backups etc. If you want to have more details on it then check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141209.aspx

Comment: Okey.thank you.But I didn't get a proper solution for a table script creation with its data.Pls help me

Comment: @Safeena:- There is no such query which can give you both the things simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on the same server or have a linked server:

CREATE TABLE tblCountry

SET IDENTITY_INSERT tblCountry ON

INSERT INTO [database2].tblCountry
SELECT * FROM [database1].tblCountry

SET IDENTITY_INSERT tblCountry OFF

Answer (score 0):

The most Easy way for this problem is for you to

1. **Right Click** on the Database on the **Object Explorer**
2. click **Generate Scripts**
3. on the introduction click **Next**
4. Select radio button on **Script entire database and all database
   objects** or you can just select specific tables or stored
   procedures by selecting the other radio button
5. On the Set Scripting Options click on Advanced Select the things you
   want to script
6. Then on the Query just change the database name after the query USE
   db2

Answer (score -1):

Right click on database and click on tasks and export data

you can use export data option in sql server...it will give you data with table script